# Move a file into another folder on disk - Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directory-structure

I've created some classes in VS and I can't move them in the folder I want them to be.
they are in the same folder of the project, at the root. But I'd like them to be in a "source" folder.

If I move them from the solution explorer they don't appear at the same place in the Windows explorer. And if I move them from the Windows explorer, or from the Folder view of VS, I can't build anymore because the files are not found.

Moreover, the main.cpp file happens to be outside of the project folder, it appears in the solution explorer but not in the folder view (in VS).
The Folder View takes the folder where the project is as root. I can't see what's before that root.

It sounds messy, I know, but that's how it was when I downloaded the project.

On the left image, you can see all my created classes are in the root, I want them to be in the source folder.

On the right image you can see that main.cpp is in the solution explorer, but not in the Folder View 
(I can expand all the folders if you'd like to see, it's not inside.)

[image]

To conclude :

How can I move my classes into the Source folder?

And how can I move the main.cpp file inside of my project folder, ideally in the source folder as well?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the easiest way to achieve what you are looking for is to remove the files you want to move from the solution (right click remove). Then you can move the files to where you want them in the windows explorer, and then add them back into the solution in the right folder.

Comment: Great! Simple and efficient, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This does not always produce the same vcxproj contents before/after. In particular it might re-add the items to a different ItemGroup than you had them in before, which can change the build order and make the build fail until you manually fix your vcxproj.

Comment: let me voice my utter distaste for this insane feature.  It's a file explorer-like-widget that doesn't actually move files????????????????????

Answer (score 1):

FOR ME... as an unreal dev the easiest solution was to delete the damn project files and regenerate them after moving them in explorer.  I'd suggest the same for anyone who has a similar tool to generate project files.